Formulating the dynamics of mass distribution in Newton-Cartan gravity
I am a mathematician following the lectures of Schuller about General Relativity, in particular this lecture. My main motivation is to understand how do we use Einstein field equation to model a gravitating system, but I want to get first the following simpler case.
In Newton-Cartan theory, spacetime is defined as $(\mathcal{M},  \nabla, t)$, where $\mathcal{M}$ represents a 4-dimensional smooth manifold, and $t: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function called absolute time. The following conditions are required:

$(dt)_p \neq 0$ for all $p \in \mathcal{M}$, ensuring the concept of absolute space.
$\nabla dt = 0$, meaning time flows uniformly.
$\nabla$ is torsion-free.

Additionally, the connection $\nabla$ is governed by the following Einstein-like equation involving the mass distribution $\rho$:
$$
Ric_{00} = \frac{8\pi G}{2} \rho,
$$
with $Ric$ being the Ricci tensor of $\nabla$.
Given this, suppose we have an initial mass distribution $\rho(0,x)=\rho_0(x)$ in a (1+1)-dimensional spacetime. How can we formulate the dynamics of the mass distribution $\rho(t,x)$ and the connection $\nabla$, given by the Christoffel symbols  $\Gamma^i_{jk}(t,x)$, over time?
Observe that
$$
Ric_{00} = \partial_k \Gamma^k_{00} - \partial_0 \Gamma^k_{0k} + \Gamma^k_{00} \Gamma^l_{kl} - \Gamma^k_{0l} \Gamma^l_{0k}
$$
and the only non zero $\Gamma$s is ${\Gamma^{1}}_{00}$, so
$$
Ric_{00} = \partial_1 \Gamma^1_{00},
$$
so we have
$$
\partial_1 \Gamma^1_{00}=4\pi G \rho.
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma^1_{00}(t,x)=4\pi G \rho(t,x)
$$
At this point, we have an ODE with two unknowns, for every value of $t$. And I can compute, for $t=0$ a value for $\Gamma^1_{00}(0,x)$. With this I can compute the geodesic followed by any particle "near" $t=0$. But then, for $t=0+\epsilon$, I will have another connection, given by  the new $\Gamma^1_{00}(\epsilon,x)$, since the particles in the mass distribution will have changed their positions.
How can we deal with this? Have I missed something?
Edit: In my path to understand this, and General Relativity afterwards, I have posted this simpler question, but unfortunately I didn't obtained any answer, too. I have written my own answer, but I am not sure it is ok. I would be happy if somebody could confirm my answer is correct (a single comment), in such a way that I can follow my journey.

I do not see why you think that $Ric_{00} = \partial_1 \Gamma^1_{00},$. Why do you think, that all other terms vanish.

I am following this, see page 66. The aim is to provide Newton equation the look of a geodesic equation for a undetermined connection $\nabla$. And this choice for the $\Gamma$s is made
